# Flutter / FireStore is there a 'right' class or approach to reordering ListTiles created from a Firestore database

Tags: drag-and-drop, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My final goal is to have a setlist of songs in Firestore...the songs in a setlist would be presented as tiles with song info like Title, Artist, Genre, etc.

Then those tiles would be sortable so you can reorder your setlist...with the order (or index?) passing back to Firestore.

I have a working ListView.builder that is returning song data from Firestore into ListTiles.  The best I've been able to come up with is having a sortOrder field that I manually edit on the tile.  The FS snapshot is doing an .orderBy('sortOrder') ... so when I change the sortOrder value on the tile the list reorders in real time...that's kind of nice...but what I really want is something like an "Edit Setlist" icon in the appBar that adds a hamburger icon say in the top right corner of the tile...then I can drag around the tiles vertically to reorder ... then upon done editing save the indexes back to FS.  I am open to any ideas.

I have tried the package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_list_drag_and_drop

But I can only see how to make it work with a List.

I have looked at ReorderableListView: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html

But I am new to Flutter and my current solution uses ListView.builder.

There does not seem to be a ReorderableListView.builder comparable option.

Thanks for any ideas.

ER

Comment: Did you fix this problem? If so, can you provide the solution, please?